# Let $g: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ integrable and $g \ge 0 $. If $\int_a^b g = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:**

Let $g: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ integrable and $g \ge 0 $. If $\int_a^b g = 0$, then for every $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ integrable implies $$\int_a^b (f · g) = 0$$

**Attempt:**

The set of points of $[a, b]$ where $g \neq 0$ has empty interior, so the points of the set $[a, b]$ where $(f · g)$ has empty interior too, then we have $$\int_a^b |f · g|  = 0$$

So, in this case, can I say $$\int_a^b |f · g|  = 0 \Rightarrow \int_a^b f · g  = 0$$

I can't justify this argument.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does "integrable" mean?  Riemann, Lebesgue, something else?

Comment: @JonasMeyer In my text only says "integrable" .. i think Riemann does the job. Ty the comment.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Is the problem 29 at page 357. The book is "Elon Lages, Um Curso de Analise 1" is a portuguese book. I have the pdf if you want.. Is a real analysis introduction and doesn't have Lebesgue integration, measure theory

Comment: the definition used is Riemann .. and some characterizations, for example, "the function discontinuity set has measure zero".. That's what I used on scratch..

Comment: Thanks.  That is useful context, and in particular, knowing that you have access to that theorem about discontinuities is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your argument

$$\Bigg|\int f \ g  \Bigg| \leq  \int |fg|  = 0$$

shows what you want.

Alternatively,

As $f$ is integrable on the given conditions, we have that $f$ is bounded. Then as $g\geq 0 $ we will have

$$\Bigg|\int f \ g  \Bigg| \leq  \int |f|\  |g| \leq M \int |g| = M\int g  = 0 $$

Nota: Estudando por esse livro ai mesmo.

Comment: Se tiver alguma pergunta, fique a vontade.

Comment: I like the second approach.  For the first approach, what is written here is true but finishing depends on the first part of the argument given in the question, where it is not explained why the emptiness of the interior of the set where $fg\neq 0$ leads to the conclusion that $\int|fg|=0$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer You're right, it lacks consistency, I guess. I've just showed why $\int fg = 0$, assuming his proof was correct up to this point. The second approach is how I would do it.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Muito obrigado amigo. Acredito que com sua dica finaliza o problema.

Comment: @RicardoGomes Tranquilo meu caro! Dê uma olhada na segunda prova, e vc fez 24?

Comment: @AaronMaroja Eu não consegui bolar um exemplo para esse exercício. Caso eu consiga, eu coloco aqui. Abraços.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\{ g> 1/n \}$ has measure $0$ because otherwise $\int g \ge \int_{\{g>1/n\}} 1/n$ would be positive. So the set $\{g > 0\} = \bigcup_n \{g > 1/n\}$ has measure zero. As a consequence also the set $\{fg \neq 0\} \subset \{ g \neq 0\} = \{ g>0\}$ has measure zero, and the result follows.